# Mocking AutoFac Root from IServiceProvider

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, moq, autofac

I'm currently using the Autofac.DependencyInjection module as well as the Autofac.Moq module too.  I am writing a unit test for trying to resolve commands and get the following exception - `Unable to retrieve Autofac root lifetime scope from service provider of type Castle.Proxies.IServiceProviderProxy.` So this leads me to a couple of questions, how could I mock or get access to this Autofac Root? Are any of these options possible?

Note: I am also not sure if this unit test is correctly using the Autofac.Moq module, or if the  test itself is  valid.

```
    [Fact]
    public void TestCommandBus()
    {
        using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose()) {
            var bus = mock.Create<CommandBus>();
            bus.Send(new TestCommand());
            Assert.Equal(1, TestCommandHandler.Value);
        }
    }


    public class TestCommand : ICommand { }
    public class TestCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<TestCommand>
    {
        public static int Value { get; set; }
        public void Handle(TestCommand command)
        {
            Value = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

CommandBus.cs

```
    public class CommandBus : ICommandBus
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        public CommandBus(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;  
        }
        public void Send<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand
        {
             using (var scope = _serviceProvider.GetAutofacRoot().BeginLifetimeScope())
            { 
                var handlers = scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>>().ToList();
                if (handlers.Count == 1)
                {
                    handlers[0].Handle(command);
                }
                else if (handlers.Count == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Command does not have any handler {command.GetType().Name}");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Too many registred handlers - {handlers.Count} for command {command.GetType().Name}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I'd question whether there's any reason to mock this. If you're trying to test the behavior of your dependency injection, it's far easier and makes more sense to just the configure the whole thing including Autofac and test that. It's easier if you create a standalone class that configures your container. Execute it and then try to resolve what you want to resolve without mocking anything.

Comment: Hi  @ScottHannen, Thanks for the reply. i've actually thought about that approach - and I considered it as a last resort.  Ideally, i'd like to keep the  integration with the Autofac.DependencyInjection Module(The module providing the extension method). Is there anyway  I could build the unit test while still maintaining  this integration? If the answer is no, would you recommend a singleton to configure the container?

Comment: Agreed, don't mock DI, just set it up with mocks inside it (if needed). Build the container then new up an AutofacServiceProvider and pass your container in. Done. Plenty of docs and examples of that sort of thing.

Comment: @TravisIllig Worked like a charm. Thanks to both of you :)